# Android draw bitmap on polygons

Tags: android, opengl-es, canvas

I am trying to draw a bitmap on a polygon has sides more than 4. ı am dealing with opengl to do this but i realised in 2d there is a method called drawBitmapMesh in Canvas for this. It worked for 4 side polygon but not working for 5.
This works

```
float verts[] = {0,0, 0,10, 0,20 ,0,30, 10,0, 10,10, 10,20, 10,30, 20,0, 20,10, 20,20, 20,30, 30,0, 30,10, 30,20, 30,30};
canvas.drawBitmapMesh(bitmap, 3, 3, verts, 0, null, 0, null);
```

This does not work gives runtime error.

```
float verts[] = {0,0, 0,10, 0,20 ,0,30, 0,40, 10,0, 10,10, 10,20, 10,30,10,40, 20,0, 20,10, 20,20, 20,30,20,40, 30,0, 30,10, 30,20, 30,30,30,40};
canvas.drawBitmapMesh(bitmap, 4, 4, verts, 0, null, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmapMesh%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20float%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%5b%5d,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29):

> verts     Array of x,y pairs, specifying where the mesh should be drawn. There must be at least (meshWidth+1) * (meshHeight+1) * 2 + meshOffset values in the array

You have 38 values in your array, whereas the above calculation with the parameters gives: (4+1)*(4+1)*2 + 0 = 50 values ...